# Eclipse has multiple issues after JRE-6 (OpenJDK) upgrade

Tags: eclipse, openjdk

I'm on 12.04 LTS, and trying to use Eclipse Indigo.

This morning Ubuntu made me update the following packages:

> Preparing to replace icedtea-6-jre-cacao 6b24-1.11.3-1ubuntu0.12.04.1 (using .../icedtea-6-jre-cacao_6b24-1.11.4-1ubuntu0.12.04.1_amd64.deb) ...
>   Unpacking replacement icedtea-6-jre-cacao ...
>   Preparing to replace openjdk-6-jre-lib 6b24-1.11.3-1ubuntu0.12.04.1 (using .../openjdk-6-jre-lib_6b24-1.11.4-1ubuntu0.12.04.1_all.deb) ...
>   Unpacking replacement openjdk-6-jre-lib ...
>   Preparing to replace icedtea-6-jre-jamvm 6b24-1.11.3-1ubuntu0.12.04.1 (using .../icedtea-6-jre-jamvm_6b24-1.11.4-1ubuntu0.12.04.1_amd64.deb) ...
>   Unpacking replacement icedtea-6-jre-jamvm ...
>   Preparing to replace openjdk-6-jre-headless 6b24-1.11.3-1ubuntu0.12.04.1 (using .../openjdk-6-jre-headless_6b24-1.11.4-1ubuntu0.12.04.1_amd64.deb) ...
>   Unpacking replacement openjdk-6-jre-headless ...
>   Preparing to replace openjdk-6-jre 6b24-1.11.3-1ubuntu0.12.04.1 (using .../openjdk-6-jre_6b24-1.11.4-1ubuntu0.12.04.1_amd64.deb) ...
>   Unpacking replacement openjdk-6-jre ...

After that (but I cannot swear it is the root cause), I have the following issues in Eclipse:

- When trying to launch the simplest HelloWorld program (which behaves fine with manual `javac`/`java`), I get either nothing or:

  > An internal error occurred during: "Launching HelloWorld".
  >    org/eclipse/jdt/debug/core/JDIDebugModel
- I get an "Error log" tab in the console panel, with an error:

  > Could not create the view: An unexpected exception was thrown.

  (Follows a consequent NullPointerException stacktrace between `sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfoFile.getZoneIDs(ZoneInfoFile.java:785)` and `org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1386)`)
- When trying to access the `Installed JREs` part of the preferences, I get a popup saying:

  > Unable to create the selected preference page.
  >   An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.jdt.debug.ui (162).

  And the preference tab says `An error has occurred when creating this preference page.`

Until today I had a manually installed Eclipse (one of the official bundles available on their site), I've tried to replace it by the repository version and I get the same errors.

What should I do to make Eclipse work again?

Another person reports: Same happened to me after updating last night. Already tried reinstalling Eclipse and Java, starting Eclipse with -clean and starting new workspace and new .eclipse dir, but nothing helps.

Comment: The accepted solution works fine, but the problem can also be avoided by using an Oracle JRE and [solving a small SWT issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10165693/ubuntu-eclipse-cannot-load-swt-libraries-not-opening).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem today. First, a little googling brought me to your issue (didn't assumed to be due to OpenJDK). After a little more research, finally solved this strange behaviour: have a look at this [ubuntu-bug](http://www.mail-archive.com/ubuntu-bugs@lists.ubuntu.com/msg3807958.html).

So the **quick solution** is just to run `sudo apt-get --reinstall install tzdata-java`
(reinstalling *Time zone and daylight-saving time data for use by java runtimes*)

Cheers

Comment: Worked for OpenJDK 7 as well.

Answer (score 4):

No idea why, but putting the line

```
-Dcom.ibm.icu.util.TimeZone.DefaultTimeZoneType=ICU
```

at the end of `eclipse.ini` seems to have solved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Brüno's answer worked for me too! It also fixed a bug that this caused in the application I am developing. Since a recent package upgrade in which the `cacao` virtual machine was removed, timestamps in my database that were in daylight savings time were interpreted incorrectly (off by one hour). But reinstalling `tzdata-java` fixed that too.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm Brüno's suggestion works well. Thank you!

The following resolves the issue, adding this line to eclipse.ini:

```
-Dcom.ibm.icu.util.TimeZone.DefaultTimeZoneType=ICU
```

Or re-installing a missing package.

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install tzdata-java
```

I have been dealing with missing and broken packages ever since Ubuntu's last upgrade!

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add, that I had the same issue; after the same update a java class was not being loaded by Eclipse. same bug posted by bruno for amd64

But I right away went to eclipse and checked for updates **do not do this**. After updating twice Eclipse now doesnt even load plugins (so no perspectives, start java projects, etc)

Then I updated to oracle's jre; the problem persists.

I am attempted[this reinstall](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1412320), plus removed ~/.eclipse/ and achieved a clean reinstall.

The problem stated in this question **is not solved** doing this, but with Bruno's answer it is now solved.

```
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea7 2.3.2) (7u7-2.3.2-1ubuntu0.12.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.2-b09, mixed mode)
```